# Парсинг сайта с разных IP

Tags: php, парсер

Каким образом можно парсить какой-либо сайт с разных *IP*, чтобы избежать бана?

До этого парсила просто с `file_get_contents`, но, конечно, начали банить.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, что-нибудь по этому поводу.

Comment: Используйте `curl` + прокси

Comment: Чтобы не банили запрашивайте страницы сайта с паузами в несколько секунд.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно банят не по ip. Учитывается как минимум ip и хедеры, отправляемые клиентом. Т.к. несколько юзеров могут работать с одного ip.

Советую сгенерировать несколько сотен хедеров, что бы эмулировать разные браузеры/ос, если этого не хватает - можно юзать прокси. Если кодите на чистом пхп - прокси и хедеры можно через `curl` устанавливать. http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php

Или можете порыть интернет, есть куча отличных либ для этих целей. Я использую https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Comment: Про ip вы не правы. Если идет скан сайта с одного ip, его и банят. Пусть там хоть 100500 хедеров проскакивает.

Comment: Всякое может быть. Но конкретно в моей практике смена хедеров, типа user-agent, всегда помогала. Например мой интернет провайдер имеет один внешний ip и соответственно около 15к пользователей из под одного ip'шника лазят по гуглам и другим сервисам. Если отслеживать только ip - то запросы разных юзеров будут считаться DoS атакой

Comment: У меня вылезала ошибка: "К сожалению, доступ с вашего IP-адреса временно ограничен. Мы обнаружили на нём подозрительную активность, нарушающую работоспособность. Если спустя некоторое время доступ не появится, то напишите нам, указав ваш IP-адрес, провайдера и город проживания. "

Попробую повозиться с cURL, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Виктория В свою защиту скажу, что ваш ip уже добавили в чёрный список. Если бы вы со старту использовали разные user-agent - всё было бы нормально.... скорее всего. Опять таки всё зависит от настроек сервера-цели )

Answer (score 0):

Надо просто нагуглить список прокси и использовать их, по небольшому количеству страниц через каждый.

Comment: Не могу сообразить, может подскажете - как лучше менять прокси каждые несколько страниц. К примеру, я запускаю кроном файл со скриптом, который получает страницу, каждые 4 минуты. Как мне каждый раз менять прокси?

Comment: @Виктория, я бы включил код смены прокси в скрипт.

Comment: Эм.. А при чём тут крон? Или ты всё время одну и ту же страницу качаешь?

Comment: нет, не одну, парсер проходится по постраничной навигации каталога, сохраняя значение последней пройденной страницы... Возможно не самое гениальное решение, но я новичок в этом деле:)

Comment: @Victoria, ну так пусть и прокси тем же способом запомнит.